# module to pass data to another modules function

Tags: python, function, module

I try to write a simple app that shows sqlite database data to a pygkt treeview.

So far I 've made five modules one called `pycheckbook.py` which imports all the others and instantiates the `MainWindow` class that is in the second module named `mainwindow.py`. Third module is `checkwindow.py` which contains  the class that show the form I use to fill or update the database. The fourth module is `searchcheck.py` who's class creates the form I use to enter various criteria to search for data (according to dates, names etc).

So after having created a query in `searchcheck.py` I want to run a function from the `MainWindow` class which is in `mainwindow.py` so as to execute the search query and refresh the treeview with the desired data.

So far I've tried:

```
def find_data(self):
    #creates query
    import mainwindow
    mainwindow.show_search_checks(query)
```

but I get the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'show_search_checks'` while when tried the:

```
def find_data(self):
    #creates query
    import pycheckbook
    mw.show_search_checks(query)
```

the function almost runs but a) reopens mainwindow (like executing the `pycheckbook` script all over) and b)the query (which is a string) doesn't pass to the `show_search_checks` function.

Thats how `pycheckbook.py` is like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mainwindow
import checkwindow
mw = mainwindow.MainWindow()
mw.showGUI()
mw.main()
```

I feel I do something wrong with the `import` of many modules (I already read that circular imports are not supported). What I think I need to do is to execute in a module a function of a given instance but Python doesn't understand it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You need the instance of `MainWindow` to call its `show_search_checks()` method. In your second `find_data()`, you create a module-level one when `pycheckbook.py` is imported, so try using `pycheckbook.mw.show_search_checks(query)` in `find_data()`.

Comment: I made some progress when I did as you instructed but still a second mainwindow is shown and nothing else happens. The progress is that when I rty to close it (running its destroy function by pressing a button) it shows the query (so it has reached to the "second" main window. Pressing the exit button again, exits the programm alltogether.

Comment: There should probably only be one `MainWindow` instance, namely the one created when `pycheckbook.py` is first `import`ed. That means that _all_ references in your program to it or one of its methods should be to the one (and only one) created in `pycheckbook.mw`.

Comment: They all do. I was suspecting that `checksearch.py` and `checkwindow.py` might cause that since the both have functions that will ask for `pycheckbook` to be imported (fearing that importing the module which is the "starter" of the programm, generated a second instance of `MainWindow`. Unfortunately that is not the case. Could creating instance of `CheckForm` via a func in `mainwindow.py` cause a re-creation of `MainWindow`? It's crazy but I really don't see anything else to look into.

Comment: Imported modules are cached in `sys.modules` which is effectively a dictionary mapping module names to loaded module instances. Whenever one is imported a check is made to see if there's an already instance of it present in the cache, and if there is, that value is returned. This means that normally the code in the body of a module will only be executed once, the first time it's the subject of an `import` statement and not in the cache. All your references to `pycheckbook.mw` after importation of `pycheckbook` should resolve to the same instance of `MainWindow`.

Comment: I feel I should mention that by putting all classes in one module, the program run just fine. Still I haven't understood how to call a classes function from another module.

Comment: In your question, `show_search_checks()` looks like it's a **method** -- a special type of function associated with instances of a particular class. That means the proper way to call is to first create one a `MainWindow`class instance (which you do in the `pycheckbook.py` module). This is why a `mw.show_search_checks(query)` "almost runs" instead of producing an `AttributeError` like the `mainwindow.show_search_checks(query)` call did. Besides class definitions, modules can also define variables holding any kind of value like integers, strings, or class _instances_ (like `mw`).